# How to combine duplicates in associative array?

Tags: javascript, replace, merge, duplicates, associative-array

What is the most concise and efficient way to find out if a JavaScript array contains duplicates and merge them into new array please ?

I tried Lodash / d3 / underscoreJs but none of them generate clean result so I tried this code ->

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "title": "My unique title",
        "link": "domainlinkto-my-unique-title",
        "image": "someurlto/my-unique-title-image",
        "date": "Mon, 29 Jul 2019 02:25:08 -0000",
        "site": "site1"
    },
    {
        "title": "A duplicate title",
        "link": "somedomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "randomurlto/a-duplicate-title.jpg",
        "date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000",
        "site": "site1"
    },
    {
        "title": "A duplicate title",
        "link": "otherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "anotherurlto/duplicate-title.jpg",
        "date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 21:09:37 -0000",
        "site": "site2"
    },
    {
        "title": "A DUPLICATE TITLE",
        "link": "someotherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "someurlto/aduplicatetitle.jpg",
        "date": "Sat, 24 Aug 2019 18:43:38 -0000",
        "site": "site3"
    },
    {
        "title": "Other duplicate: title",
        "link": "anydomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "anotherdomainurlto/other-duplicate-title.jpg",
        "date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000",
        "site": "site2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Other duplicate : title",
        "link": "anyotherdomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "exampleurlto/hjKGHK45huu.jpg",
        "date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000",
        "site": "site5"
    },
    {
        "title": "Other unique title",
        "link": "anydomainlinkto-other-unique-title/",
        "image": "anyotherurlto/img/other-title.jpg",
        "date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:18:10 -0000",
        "site": "site3"
    }
        ];
    Array.prototype.groupBy = function (props) {
        var arr = this;
        var partialResult = {};
        var imgResult = {};
        arr.forEach(el=>{
            var grpObj = {};
            var grpImg = {};
        props.forEach(prop=>{
            grpObj.title = el.title;
            grpImg.image = el.image;
        });
        var key = JSON.stringify(grpObj);
        var keyImg = JSON.stringify(grpImg);
        if(!imgResult[key]) {
            imgResult[key] = grpImg.image;
        } else {
            imgResult[key] = el.image;
        }
        if(!partialResult[key]) partialResult[key] = [];
            partialResult[key].push(
            {
            link: el.link,
            site: el.site, 
            date: el.date 
            });
        });
        var finalResult = Object.keys(partialResult, imgResult).map(key=>{
            var keyObj = JSON.parse(key);
            keyObj.links = partialResult[key];
            keyObj.image = imgResult[key];
            return keyObj;
        })
        return finalResult;}

    var filtered = arr.groupBy(['title']);
    console.log(filtered);
```

BUT...
As you can see [titles] in UPPERCASE and "Other duplicate : title" is not taken as duplicate

WHAT I WOULD DO --->

```js
var expected = [
    {
        "title": "My unique title",
        "links": [{"date": "Mon, 29 Jul 2019 02:25:08 -0000","site": "site1", "link": "domainlinkto-my-unique-title"}],
        "image": "someurlto/my-unique-title-image",
    },
    {
        "title": "My duplicate title",
        "links": [
     {"date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000","site": "site1","link":"somedomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/"},
     {"date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 21:09:37 -0000","site": "site2","link": "otherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/"},
     {"date": "Sat, 24 Aug 2019 18:43:38 -0000","site": "site3","link": "someotherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/"}
     ],
        "image": "randomurlto/a-duplicate-title.jpg",
    },
    {
        "title": "Other duplicate: title",
        "links": [
     {"date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000","site": "site2","link":"anydomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/"},
     {"date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000","site": "site5","link": "anyotherdomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/"}
     ],
        "image": "anotherdomainurlto/other-duplicate-title.jpg",
    },
    {
        "title": "Other unique title",
        "links": [{"date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:18:10 -0000","site": "site1", "link": "anydomainlinkto-other-unique-title/"}],
        "image": "anyotherurlto/img/other-title.jpg",
        "site": "site3"
    }
];
console.log(expected);
```

Hi Genious

What is the most concise and efficient way to find out if a JavaScript array contains duplicates and merge them into new array please ?

I tried Lodash / d3 / underscoreJs but none of them generate clean result so I tried this code ->

```js
var arr = [
    {
        "title": "My unique title",
        "link": "domainlinkto-my-unique-title",
        "image": "someurlto/my-unique-title-image",
        "date": "Mon, 29 Jul 2019 02:25:08 -0000",
        "site": "site1"
    },
    {
        "title": "A duplicate title",
        "link": "somedomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "randomurlto/a-duplicate-title.jpg",
        "date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000",
        "site": "site1"
    },
    {
        "title": "A duplicate title",
        "link": "otherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "anotherurlto/duplicate-title.jpg",
        "date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 21:09:37 -0000",
        "site": "site2"
    },
    {
        "title": "A DUPLICATE TITLE",
        "link": "someotherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "someurlto/aduplicatetitle.jpg",
        "date": "Sat, 24 Aug 2019 18:43:38 -0000",
        "site": "site3"
    },
    {
        "title": "Other duplicate: title",
        "link": "anydomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "anotherdomainurlto/other-duplicate-title.jpg",
        "date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000",
        "site": "site2"
    },
    {
        "title": "Other duplicate : title",
        "link": "anyotherdomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/",
        "image": "exampleurlto/hjKGHK45huu.jpg",
        "date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000",
        "site": "site5"
    },
    {
        "title": "Other unique title",
        "link": "anydomainlinkto-other-unique-title/",
        "image": "anyotherurlto/img/other-title.jpg",
        "date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:18:10 -0000",
        "site": "site3"
    }
        ];
    Array.prototype.groupBy = function (props) {
        var arr = this;
        var partialResult = {};
        var imgResult = {};
        arr.forEach(el=>{
            var grpObj = {};
            var grpImg = {};
        props.forEach(prop=>{
            grpObj.title = el.title;
            grpImg.image = el.image;
        });
        var key = JSON.stringify(grpObj);
        var keyImg = JSON.stringify(grpImg);
        if(!imgResult[key]) {
            imgResult[key] = grpImg.image;
        } else {
            imgResult[key] = el.image;
        }
        if(!partialResult[key]) partialResult[key] = [];
            partialResult[key].push(
            {
            link: el.link,
            site: el.site, 
            date: el.date 
            });
        });
        var finalResult = Object.keys(partialResult, imgResult).map(key=>{
            var keyObj = JSON.parse(key);
            keyObj.links = partialResult[key];
            keyObj.image = imgResult[key];
            return keyObj;
        })
        return finalResult;}

    var filtered = arr.groupBy(['title']);
    console.log(filtered);
```

BUT...
As you can see [titles] in UPPERCASE and "Other duplicate : title" is not taken as duplicate

WHAT I WOULD DO --->

```js
[
    {
        "title": "My unique title",
        "links": [{"date": "Mon, 29 Jul 2019 02:25:08 -0000","site": "site1", "link": "domainlinkto-my-unique-title"}],
        "image": "someurlto/my-unique-title-image",
    },
    {
        "title": "My duplicate title",
        "links": [
     {"date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000","site": "site1","link":"somedomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/"},
     {"date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 21:09:37 -0000","site": "site2","link": "otherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/"},
     {"date": "Sat, 24 Aug 2019 18:43:38 -0000","site": "site3","link": "someotherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/"}
     ],
        "image": "randomurlto/a-duplicate-title.jpg",
    },
    {
        "title": "Other duplicate: title",
        "links": [
     {"date": "Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000","site": "site2","link":"anydomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/"},
     {"date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000","site": "site5","link": "anyotherdomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/"}
     ],
        "image": "anotherdomainurlto/other-duplicate-title.jpg",
    },
    {
        "title": "Other unique title",
        "links": [{"date": "Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:18:10 -0000","site": "site1", "link": "anydomainlinkto-other-unique-title/"}],
        "image": "anyotherurlto/img/other-title.jpg",
        "site": "site3"
    }
];
```

I'm sure this is not the better way to do that (we are agree) so I'm asking stackoverflow genious...

Thanks for reading and time spent for thinking about my problem

Comment: js is case sensitive, a property name with uppercase letters is not a duplicate of a lowercase one. If you want them to be tested as equals you need to convert both to a common case and use that as grouping key

Comment: Good approach but could you clarify your answer please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just lowercase the title before building up the json object for grouping. And I'd use object destructuring to clean up things, as well as just one hashtable, and I don't see the sense in a generic `Array.prototype.groupBy` if you hardcode properties in it:

```
  const hash = {}, result = [];

  for(const { title, link, image, date, site } of input) {
    const key = JSON.stringify({ title: title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, ""), });
    if(hash[key]) {
      hash[key].push({ link, date, site });
    } else {
      result.push({ title, image, links: hash[key] = [{ link, date, site }], });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Appreciate the help but given code doesn't fit. Run it and you'll see...

Comment: Hard to say, as the snippets you've shown all produce different results.

Comment: I'm agree with you "my code is messy" ... If you forget the code and just compare arrays you'll see I try to merge [link] of duplicates [title] (UPPERCASE & ":") into a new array. Maybe it's just impossible ?

Comment: Thats exactly what my solution does?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that because you try to help me and it's very cool but ... Could you post your code into snippet with the first array ? Because it doesn't work for me

Comment: Cause the `image` is not the same. If you group by title only, which `image` do you choose?

Comment: simply the first one image

Comment: Ah okay, well then just exclude it from the key.

Comment: Very good ! It almost that ! (I'm still in trouble with "Other duplicate: title" &  "Other duplicate : title") please see console -> https://jsfiddle.net/kthyq6bx/1/

Comment: Good answer too ! It works equals ! What is the speedest solution for you (objectivly) ? Yours or Slai's ?

Comment: Remember: You write code *for humans*, not for the computer. I write readable code (unlike others), if you want to know which one is faster, run a speed test, but I'd guess that the results don't really differ.

Comment: @JimTheCurious seems more efficient than mine because it has only 1-2 key lookups per item, and doesn't need the object values at the end, but not sure because of the unnecessary `JSON.stringify` (would be useful only if you group by multiple properties. BTW, `image` is not included in the result

Comment: You're right ! Your code is more readable (and hackable) by humans ! You're the Boss ! ^^

Comment: @slai good catch, fixed (and I'll leave the `JSON.stringify` there for extensibility)

Comment: Both are great but I prefer use Jonas answer. Just for say: Result is not the same when remove the JSON.stringify (I tried with other values)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to group by lowercase titles without spaces :

```js
var arr = [{"title":"My unique title","link":"domainlinkto-my-unique-title","image":"someurlto/my-unique-title-image","date":"Mon, 29 Jul 2019 02:25:08 -0000","site":"site1"},{"title":"A duplicate title","link":"somedomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/","image":"randomurlto/a-duplicate-title.jpg","date":"Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000","site":"site1"},{"title":"A duplicate title","link":"otherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/","image":"anotherurlto/duplicate-title.jpg","date":"Sun, 25 Aug 2019 21:09:37 -0000","site":"site2"},{"title":"A DUPLICATE TITLE","link":"someotherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/","image":"someurlto/aduplicatetitle.jpg","date":"Sat, 24 Aug 2019 18:43:38 -0000","site":"site3"},{"title":"Other duplicate: title","link":"anydomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/","image":"anotherdomainurlto/other-duplicate-title.jpg","date":"Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000","site":"site2"},{"title":"Other duplicate : title","link":"anyotherdomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/","image":"exampleurlto/hjKGHK45huu.jpg","date":"Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000","site":"site5"},{"title":"Other unique title","link":"anydomainlinkto-other-unique-title/","image":"anyotherurlto/img/other-title.jpg","date":"Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:18:10 -0000","site":"site3"}]
    
var result = arr.reduce((o, { title, image, link, date, site }, k) => (
  ( o[k = title.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')] = o[k] || { title, image, links: [] } )
  .links.push({ date, site, link }), o), {})

console.log( Object.values(result) )
```

---

If it has to work in IE too :

```js
var arr = [{"title":"My unique title","link":"domainlinkto-my-unique-title","image":"someurlto/my-unique-title-image","date":"Mon, 29 Jul 2019 02:25:08 -0000","site":"site1"},{"title":"A duplicate title","link":"somedomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/","image":"randomurlto/a-duplicate-title.jpg","date":"Sun, 25 Aug 2019 15:52:59 -0000","site":"site1"},{"title":"A duplicate title","link":"otherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/","image":"anotherurlto/duplicate-title.jpg","date":"Sun, 25 Aug 2019 21:09:37 -0000","site":"site2"},{"title":"A DUPLICATE TITLE","link":"someotherdomainlinkto-a-duplicate-title/","image":"someurlto/aduplicatetitle.jpg","date":"Sat, 24 Aug 2019 18:43:38 -0000","site":"site3"},{"title":"Other duplicate: title","link":"anydomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/","image":"anotherdomainurlto/other-duplicate-title.jpg","date":"Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000","site":"site2"},{"title":"Other duplicate : title","link":"anyotherdomainlinkto-other-duplicate-title/","image":"exampleurlto/hjKGHK45huu.jpg","date":"Mon, 26 Aug 2019 00:37:28 -0000","site":"site5"},{"title":"Other unique title","link":"anydomainlinkto-other-unique-title/","image":"anyotherurlto/img/other-title.jpg","date":"Mon, 26 Aug 2019 09:18:10 -0000","site":"site3"}];
    
var result = arr.reduce(function(o, v) {
  var key = v.title.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
  if (!o[key]) o[key] = { title: v.title, image: v.image, links: [] };
  o[key].links.push({ date: v.date, site: v.site, link: v.link });
  return o; 
}, {});

console.log( Object.keys(result).map(function(k) { return result[k]; }) );
```

Comment: This isn't code golf though. That variable as a parameter and the comma operator really just decrease readability (and performance, probably)

Comment: Perfect ! Exactly what I'm looking for ! Works like a charm at first try ! A thousand thanks ! If you have (bonus) time could you explain your answer (to sleep less dumb)

Comment: @JimTheCurious I made the second answer a bit more readable to show what is happening. It uses object where the key is the title in lowercase without spaces. If the key doesn't exist, it creates it with the title, image, links object. The rest of the properties are added to the links array. Only the values from the result object are needed at the end. Overall it is very specific grouping that would probably be harder to achieve with a library.

Comment: I'm agree too specific ! Thanks for explanations !